# Laravel Livewire 3: Wong method called on click

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, laravel-livewire

I'm new to Livewire (just installed v3 beta). When I perform a wire:click action, the method is called, and all works fine. However, when I then click on another button with another action (method), the first one is instead called.

In this example, I have two counters. If I click the second counter after the first, then the first counter is called again, and the second is never fired. Tried looking through the docs and on other issues, but cannot find anything.

```
namespace App\Livewire;

use Livewire\Component;

class Counter extends Component
{
    public $count = 1;

    public $test = 1;

    public function increment()
    {
        $this->count++;
    }

    public function anotherIncrement()
    {
        $this->test++;
    }

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.counter');
    }
}
```

```
<div>
    <h1> {{ $count }}</h1>
    <button wire:click="increment">Counter 1</button>

    <h1> {{ $test }}</h1>
    <button wire:click="anotherIncrement">Counter 2</button>
</div>
```

**Update:**

The XHR requests also show the wrong method called and I've also added some on-click javascript to show which button was clicked, along with showing what attribute method is on that button. Logging this shows the correct button, so i'm assuming this is an issue with the JavaScript which powers Livewire. Calling dd on the backend doesn't help, as it's the wrong method still.

Comment: what happens when you dd() in the function you are trying to call?

Comment: dd() shows the wrong method still, as the XHR is still requesting the wrong method. See my update

Comment: @Jay clear the cache, re-publish asserts and try

Comment: @AbdullaNilam, the cache is disabled on my Chrome inspector and I have no assets published with Livewire 3

Comment: I have updated my answer and it works as i have already tested

Answer (score -1):

I see this issue in this v3 version it wasn't there in v2 but you can just add **parenthesis** rounded brackets to do the job like below

```
<button wire:click="anotherIncrement()">Counter 2</button>
```

instead of

```
<button wire:click="anotherIncrement">Counter 2</button>
```

or you can change your second **h1** html tag to **h2** tag and see it will work too, there is some problem while morphing html.
I have tested this below code and it works, why don't you give a try.

```
<div>
    <h1> {{ $count }}</h1>
    <button wire:click="increment()">Counter 1</button>

    <h2> {{ $test }}</h2>
    <button wire:click="anotherIncrement()">Counter 2</button>
</div>
```